# Re-run a loop iteration

Tags: perl, loops

I have this program which takes a array of words and asks user to type a sentence which has each of the word from the array:

```
@words = qw(Hi world thanks);
foreach $word (@words) 
{
        print "Enter a line with word:$word\n";
        chomp($input = <STDIN>);
        if($input=~/$word/i) 
        {
                print "Great\n";
        } else {
                print "Incorrect. Type a line containing $word\n";
        }
}
```

If the user types a input with the word, it works fine. But if he doesn't It only prints the error message and moves to the next word. I want it it prompt the user to re-enter inputs for the same word. But how ? I tried next it did not work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) in this case to *restart the current iteration*.

```
foreach my $word (@words) 
{
        print "Enter a line with word:$word\n";
        chomp($input = <STDIN>);
        if($input=~/$word/i) 
        {
                print "Great\n";
        } else {
                print "Incorrect. Type a line contaning $word\n";
                redo; # restart current iteration.
        }
}
```

A less-recommended alternative is to use a [`goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html):

```
foreach my $word (@words)
{
        INPUT:print "Enter a line with word:$word\n";
        chomp($input = <STDIN>);
        if($input=~/$word/i)
        {
                print "Great\n";
        } else {
                print "Incorrect. Type a line contaning $word\n";
                goto INPUT;
        }
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, 14 upvotes for `redo`? Long time since I've seen such overwhelming acclaim in the perl tag.

Answer (score 4):

While `redo` is definitely cuter, here's a version with `while ... continue`. It relies on an inner loop that is exited only when the right word is entered, and prints a correction for each wrong answer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = qw(Hi world thanks);
foreach my $word (@words) {
    print "Enter a line with word: $word\n";
    while (my $input = <>) {
        last if $input =~ /$word/;
    } continue {
        print "Incorrect. Type a line contaning $word\n";
    }
    print "Great\n";
}
```

Note that `chomp` is not required in this case.

Comment: I guess that `chomp` really isn't needed in any of these, but only because the regex isn't anchored, and it isn't an `eq` comparison.

Comment: @JoelBerger Hence "in this case".

Comment: oh, I thought you meant in your case. Gotcha

Comment: @JoelBerger I guess it might be better practice to include `chomp`, in case someone later tries to use the code for something else, which does need chomp. I've just got this thing for simplifying code.

Answer (score 3):

I would create an infinite `while` loop to exit out of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = qw(Hi world thanks);
foreach my $word (@words) {
  print "Enter a line with word: $word\n";
  while (1) {
    chomp( my $input = <STDIN> );
    if( $input=~/$word/i )  {
      print "Great\n";
      last;
    } else {
      print "Incorrect. Type a line contaning $word\n";
    }
  }
}
```

of course I would probably separate the logic of each individual word into a sub, then loop over that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = qw(Hi world thanks);
get_word($_) for @words;

sub get_word {
  my $word = shift or die "Need a word";
  print "Enter a line with word: $word\n";
  while (1) {
    chomp( my $input = <STDIN> );
    if( $input=~/$word/i )  {
      print "Great\n";
      last;
    } else {
      print "Incorrect. Type a line contaning $word\n";
    }
  }
}
```